# Prevent my project from calling the __CxxFrameHandler3 (CRT function)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msvcrt

I was working on a **none Visual C++ Runtime Library project** for a few days from now, however, I had a smooth ingoing until my linker start complaining about the unresolved external symbol of the `__CxxFrameHandler3` CRT function, so after searching for the reason which produces this error I found that calling a method of any custom class from the main entry point is calling this CRT function, simple example :

```
// /No Common Language RunTime Support
// /Ignore All Default Libraries 

class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();

    int do_something();
private:

};

int A::do_something()
{
    return 0;
}

int EntryPoint()
{
    A a;
    a.do_something(); // Calls the __CxxFrameHandler3 CRT function.

    return 0;
}
```

Error :

```
 LNK2019    unresolved external symbol ___CxxFrameHandler3 referenced in function __unwindfunclet$?UmbraServerMain@@YGHPAUHINSTANCE__@@0PA_WH@Z$0
```

Is there a way to prevent the call to this CRT function?

Comment: Since looks like this function has to do with SEH, did you try disabling SEH and C++ exceptions in your settings?

Comment: @SergeyA,  After disabling **C++ Exceptions** it worked fine, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer:

This functions has to do with SEH (Structured Exceptions Handling), so to stop calling it, one needs to disable exceptions (SEH and C++ exceptions) in the project.

Comment: Not sure if it's specifically SEH...it might just be regular C++ exceptions. (Exceptions aren't directly implemented by the compiler; it just inserts calls to CRT functions that do the heavy lifting.)

Comment: @cHao according MSDN, it deals with SEH: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770594.aspx AFAIK, in MSVC C++ exceptions are implemented on top of SEH, so I would imagine you need to disable  both.

Comment: @cHao you are right, it is used for C++ exceptions and not for SEH (which uses _C_specific_handler). c.f. https://sanseolab.tistory.com/category/?page=6

Answer (score 1):

That function is part of VS's exception handling infrastructure. In order to safely avoid using the CRT, you'll need to either provide your own (compatible!) implementations of the exception-handling functions, or compile with exceptions disabled and religiously avoid anything that can throw an exception. (An exception you've explicitly unprepared yourself for, is a memory leak waiting to happen.)